# Need to Loop through SubQuery to pass info to other query

Tags: apex, soql, class, loop

I have a very unique problem.  I am trying to query a lot of data which passes through a junction object.  The junction object makes it complex as I can't query around it.  I need to pass the Ids from one query to the next so I can get the correct information.

SOQL Query #1:

```
SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, Owner.FirstName, Owner.LastName, Notification_Date__c, Incident_City__c, Incident_Country__r.Name, Total_Product__c, Comments_Postal_Express__c,
     (SELECT RecordType.Name, Container__c, Ship_Date__c, Date_of_Retention__c, Carrier__c, Port_of_Loading__c, Port_of_Discharge__c, Container_Type__c, Place_of_Retention__c, Vessel__c, Master_BOL__c, House_BOL__c  FROM Incident_Locations__r), 
     (SELECT Brand__c, Product_Detail__c, Product_Types__c, Total_Product_Quantity__c FROM Products__r),
     (SELECT Business__c, Case__c, Business__r.Business_Name__c, Business__r.Business_Type__c FROM BusinessCasesAssociations__r),
     (SELECT Subject_Name__r.Subject_Name__c, Subject_Name__r.Subject_Type__c FROM Subject_for_Cases__r)
FROM Case__c
WHERE Supply_Chain_Type__c = 'SEA'
```

SOQL Query #2:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Business_Name__c, Business_Type__c,
     (SELECT Street__c, Business_City__c, State_Province__c, Country__c, Zip_Postal_Code__c from BPR_Business_Addresses__r),
     (SELECT Number_Type__c, Number__c FROM Business_Phone_Numbers__r),
     (SELECT Email_Bus__c FROM Email_Businesses__r)
FROM Business__c
WHERE (Id = :[SELECT Business__c FROM BusinessCasesAssociations__r])
```

The Field that ties them together is a subquery in the first query.  I have placed it in the Where clause of the second one so you understand what I am trying to accomplish.  I am hoping that a for loop or something can tie these together.  My goal is to eventually use these in a wrapper class for a VF page.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the ID values from query 1 like this:

```
Set<Id> bIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Case__c c : [query 1]) {
    for (BusinessCasesAssociation__c bca : c.BusinessCasesAssociations__r) {
        bIds.add(bca.Business__c);
    }
}
```

and then use then in query 2 like this:

```
... [... FROM Business__c WHERE Id in :bIds];
```